# Table row CSS styling issue for IE, Firefox, and Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, html-table, tablerow

I try to outline the table row using CSS. 
For example:

http://jsfiddle.net/huifei/zg2Mf/

```
<table>
    <tr class="RowStyling">
        <td rowspan="2">Telephone:</td>
        <td>555 77 854</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>555 77 855</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But each browser give me different styling.

Question: Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Each browser renders CSS properties differently for example like your row outline, I have also had it in the past on buttons. Safari will round them off where as Firefox and Chrome will keep them square. I suggest having a read of this http://www.thesitewizard.com/css/excludecss.shtml, I have looked at this before and it seemed to be helpful. Also this http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks/.